# Heroku worker dyno keeps crashing cannot start with Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, resque

My Heroku worker keeps on crashing whenver I do restart it crashes within 5 seconds.

Below is my `Procfile`:

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake resque:work
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 RESQUE_TERM_TIMEOUT=7 bundle exec rake resque:work
```

I'm trying to get `Resque` work on the system but also unsure that if `Resque` process even started on the server. Locally I would do:

`rake resque:work QUEUE=*` and this work work perfectly.

Is there a reason why my Worker Dyno keeps on crashing also a way to check if `resque` is running successfully?

Comment: `heroku ps:restart web.1` will restart the dyno that crashed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type:

```
heroku ps
```

Which will tell you what processes are running at any given time.

```
heroku logs
```

That will obviously give you detailed information about what's happening.   Copy in your log file and I bet someone will be able to fix it for you.   My guess is you're seeing a does not exist error in there somewhere, which is something I ran into :)